# Trait diesel::Expression not implemented for NaiveDate, but it is for NaiveDateTime

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel, rust-chrono

I am trying to use `chrono::NaiveDate` as a database model field. Here is the model:

```
use chrono::{NaiveDate, NaiveDateTime};
use diesel::{Insertable, Queryable};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use crate::schema::users;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Associations, Identifiable, Queryable)]
#[table_name = "users"]
pub struct User {
    pub id: uuid::Uuid,
    pub password_hash: String,
    pub is_active: bool,

    pub is_premium: bool,
    pub premium_expiration: Option<NaiveDate>,

    pub email: String,
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub date_of_birth: NaiveDate,
    pub currency: String,

    pub modified_timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
    pub created_timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
}

#[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
#[table_name = "users"]
pub struct NewUser<'a> {
    pub id: uuid::Uuid,
    pub password_hash: &'a str,
    pub is_active: bool,

    pub is_premium: bool,
    pub premium_expiration: Option<NaiveDate>,

    pub email: &'a str,
    pub first_name: &'a str,
    pub last_name: &'a str,
    pub date_of_birth: NaiveDate,
    pub currency: &'a str,

    pub modified_timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
    pub created_timestamp: NaiveDateTime,
}
```

When I run `cargo check`, I get the following errors from rustc:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `NaiveDate: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/models/user.rs:27:17
   |
27 | #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `NaiveDate`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamp>>` for `NaiveDate`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Insertable` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `NaiveDate: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/models/user.rs:27:17
   |
27 | #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `NaiveDate`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Expression` for `&'insert NaiveDate`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamp>>` for `&'insert NaiveDate`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Insertable` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `NaiveDate: diesel::Expression` is not satisfied
  --> src/models/user.rs:27:17
   |
27 | #[derive(Debug, Insertable)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `NaiveDate`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Expression` for `&NaiveDate`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamp>>` for `&NaiveDate`
   = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Insertable` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

The relevant lines of my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde"] }
diesel = { version = "1.4", features = ["postgres", "uuidv07", "r2d2", "chrono"] }
```

Running `cargo tree | grep chrono` gives the following output, indicating there is not a version conflict with `chrono`:

```
├── chrono v0.4.19
│   ├── chrono v0.4.19 (*)
│       ├── chrono v0.4.19 (*)
```

I have used `NaiveDate` before in diesel models and have had no problem deriving the `Insertable` macro. What am I missing here that is preventing the macro from implementing `diesel::Expression` for `chono::NaiveDate` while it appears to be implemented for `chono::NaiveDateTime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your question is missing important information. This includes the corresponding `table!` call from your schema.

Now the guessing what could possibly cause this based on the information you provided:

The error message indicates that you try to insert a `NaiveDate` into a `Timestamp` field. That's just something that is not supported as a timestamp expects a data and a time value, while a `NaiveDate` only provides a date value. You can see a list of out of the box supported type mappings for diesel in the documentation of each SQL type. For example for `Timestamp` [here](https://docs.diesel.rs/1.4.x/diesel/sql_types/struct.Timestamp.html)

Comment: Silly me for forgetting to add the schema to the question description. Thank you; you were correct that I had made it a `TIMESTAMP` field in the SQL.